# Can we solve 4 queen problem using Best first search?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, artificial-intelligence

I know that we can solve this n queen problem using backtrack but my faculty had asked me to solve 4 queen problem using best first search algorithm. I tried to solve it but I can't figure out the approach. Can we take a invalid state and move queens unit steps to reach a valid state?

Comment: Are you sure that "best first search" isn't "breadth first search"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can.
You can use A* as best first algorithm. The cost function for your A* should be the number of attacked queens. For now, use this same value as heuristic too (i.e number of attacked queens). 
You can later on try out some other heuristic as well.

Comment: Ok I will try
Thanks

Comment: Okay. I have removed the pressure.:)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by **Best First Search**. From [the OptaPlanner user guide](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/) I see 3 options, explained on 4-queens:

1. **Brute Force** which is similar to **Breadth First Search**:

[image: Brute Force]

2. **Branch and bound** which is similar to **Depth First Search**:

[image: Branch and bound]

3. **First Fit (Decreasing)**:

[image]

That being said, [N-Queens is cheatable](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/05/12/CheatingOnTheNQueensBenchmark.html), so you're better off just exploiting that.

Comment: What software you use to create these graph representations of the problem, if I may ask?

Comment: Inkscape - the SVG files are in the OptaPlanner GitHub repository. Apache license, so you can reuse them as long as you attribute a source link to OptaPlanner.

Comment: Thank you kind Sir

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: Thanks for detailed answer. Also, Best-first_search description link is added in question.